# Given an unsigned integer, it's easy to swap every even and odd bit. Can this be generalized to swapping every even and odd n bits?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

In the case where n = 1, if we have an unsigned 32bit integer i, the swapped integer would be

```
((i & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((i & 0x55555555) << 1)
```

When n = 2

```
((i & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((i & 0x33333333) << 2)
```

When n = 4

```
((i & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((i & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4)
```

and so on.

What about if n is an arbitrary power of 2? ...and, let's say that i is an arbitrary 128bit integer rather than a 32bit integer so we have 7 cases rather than 5?

I suspect there is a way to generalize the process for a given n (i.e. generating that mask from n), and it would be nice to have that so that I don't necessarily have to hardcode each individual case whenever it comes up (for example, implementing certain Cryptographic Hash Functions--e.g. JH).

The obvious method that comes to mind is to loop through the potential mask, with fewer iterations in the case where n is larger but I'd rather have a method that would complete in constant time with fewer operations.

Something that should work for a 32bit integer, for instance:

```
uint32_t mask = 0; submask = (2n) - 1;

for (uint32_t index = 0; index < 32; index += 2n)
{
    mask |= submask;
    submask <<= 2n;
}
```

Is there a better way to generate that mask (ideally without the loop)?

edit: Just occurred to me that instead of

```
((i & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((i & 0x55555555) << 1)
```

you could do

```
((i & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((i << 1) & 0xaaaaaaaa)
```

which would allow wouldn't require the use of the inverted mask at all.  On the off chance someone were to view this for reference, that might be convenient.

Comment: Personally, I'd just use a table of masks. You only need seven masks though, not 14, because each left side mask can be converted to a right side mask by right shifting it by the same amount you'd left shift the result. So for example, `((i & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((i & 0x55555555) << 1)` can be "simplified" to `mask = 0xaaaaaaaa`, `((i & mask) >> 1) | ((i & (mask >> 1)) << 1)`. That is `0x55555555` is just `0xaaaaaaaa >> 1`, `0x33333333` is the same as `0xcccccccc >> 2`, etc.

Comment: In some cases, I would default to doing that.  However, in some of the contexts I'm working with there is a downside to having another table (either by pushing the memory footprint a little higher or by increasing the number of register spills).  Still, if that's the best way to go, that's what I'll do.  That said, I am curious if there are any novel approaches I haven't considered.

Comment: @ShadowRanger generating the other mask just requires negating the first one i.e. 0x55555555 = ~0xaaaaaaaa etc. You can save a shift that way.

Comment: @Nick: True. Both instructions are cheap, but bitwise invert is cheaper. Should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

This method is somewhat more efficient I think. You can either store or generate the first mask value. Forgive me if my c++ isn't quite right, I'm more of a php/javascript programmer. This code will generate all the masks in turn, so you could save them into an array or just stop the loop at the mask you wanted:

```
uint32_t mask = 0xffffffff; // can perhaps use int32 and -1?
for (uint32_t i = 4; i >= 0; i--)  {
   mask ^= mask >> (1 << i);
   cout << mask;
}
```

Comment: I get zeros running this code. Could you post complete working code?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "0xffffffff" instead of "0b11111...", in which case it does seem to iteratively generate the masks.  Possibly helpful.  Can it work in reverse?  That is, could you generate 0xcccccccc from 0xaaaaaaaa and 0xf0f0f0f0 from 0xcccccccc in a similar way instead of the other way around?

Comment: @GRC I don't have access to c++ so this code is adapted from some PHP i wrote. But other than removal of $ signs in front of variable names it's identical. Also seems to work for OP

Comment: @MNagy yes 0xffffffff (or -1). Will edit post and think about doing it the other way around.

Comment: @MNagy I'm pretty sure it won't work the other way around as it would require advance knowledge of what the next mask is, which is kind of hard when you're trying to generate it with the same line of code! :)

Comment: @GRC does changing 0b111... to 0xffffffff help? The equivalent code in PHP (`$mask = 0xffffffff; for ($i = 4; $i >= 0; $i--) $mask ^= $mask >> (1 << $i);`) produces the expected results.

Comment: I ask about the other way around because the code I'm working on (a cryptographic hash function called JH) switches bits in that way.  That said, it looks like a step in the direction of what I'm searching for.